# Replica leadership in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I would like to have more details on the leadership of a replica (ie. `system.replicas.is_leader`) in a ClickHouse DB.

The documentation states the following :

```
is_leader:          Whether the replica is the leader.
Only one replica can be the leader at a time. The leader is responsible for selecting background merges to perform.
Note that writes can be performed to any replica that is available and has a session in ZK, regardless of whether it is a leader.
```

This appears vague to me.
Does someone have more details about a leader replica?

- Is there something to care about with a leader replica?
- Can I read/write to/from a leader replica, like a standard one?
- How does the leader election work?
- When do the leadership change?

Answer (score 1):

Leader replica just coordinates some background processes, leveraging ZooKeeper cluster. So unlike master/slave setup in other DBMS, in ClickHouse you shouldn't care about replica leadership status for reads and writes.

More details are over here: https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/replication/

Comment: Thanks Ivan for your reply. could you please explain what kind of background processes that the leader coordinates? what's impact if those processes are stoped?